# Log4j doesn't create any file using log4j.properties

Tags: java, logging

I have a problem with creating a log file using log4j.properties. File is not generated. No matter what I try. Here's log from Tomcat:

```
INFO: Initializing log4j from [/usr/share/tomcat7/webapps/Money/WEB-INF/classes /log4j.properties]
lis 03, 2013 10:37:29 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
```

**web.xml**

```
    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/log4j.properties</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.util.Log4jConfigListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>log4jRefreshInterval</param-name>
        <param-value>10000</param-value>
    </context-param>
```

**log4j.properties**

```
# Root logger option
log4j.debug=true
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, file, stdout
# Direct log messages to a log file
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=logs/money.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=1MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=1
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{ABSOLUTE} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
# Direct log messages to stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

and here's how I use my logger:

```
private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(HomeController.class);
```

and i.e. :

```
LOGGER.debug("Finding user by email FAILED");
```

Comment: try setting the log path to ${catalina.base}/logs/money.log. What OS are you using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to add catalina.home variable:

```
log4j.appender.file.File=${catalina.home}/logs/money.log
```